# REST API JSON transmission

Tags: c#, android, rest

I am building an Android client that communicates with an api by sending and receiving JSON.

My question is, can I assume if I get a 200 status back from my api, that all data passed from my Android app (sessionID, device details) to my api, and all data passed back to my Android app from the API, has ALL been received and dealt with accordingly, or should I be checking the size of the data sent and received?

Thanks.
James.

Comment: You should try hitting the endpoint address in chrome. Use F12 to get developer tools up and check the "network" tab. If you then click on the api call's url you should be presented with a tab on the right of the screen called "response" this should present you with the json object that is sent back. If there is no object then there is an issue with the api. If it is a populated object then the issue is with the way the object is being rendered. I hope this helps?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am not having any issues with it, and everything is being sent/received...I am just not certain that there may be some issues in the future with data transmission.

Comment: How are you sending and receiving your JSON?

Comment: If you are worried about the data that is received you can add some validation code in your api to check the deserialized request object and return a 400 bad request response code if the request object fails validation. That is a commonly used pattern.

Comment: I am sending json from android using jsonobject, the mvc model binder creates my device detail objects and I process accordingly in my methods...then if everything is ok, send back a 200 with the return data or the relevant code, 401, etc etc... I am then checking this code back in my Android client and using GSON to give me an object created from my result.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Yes

HTTP, and by extension REST, presumes a reliable transport layer protocol, which means that you will either receive every part of a message, or no part of it. Thus if you receive any response (not just 200 OK), you can naturally assume that your entire request was sent to the server successfully, and you've receive the entire response.

Comment: Not true on the receiving end.  If I pull the plug between packets 1 and 2 of the response you can still read the first packet but the rest of the data will never come.  Its up to higher level APIs to figure out the rest of the data is never coming and not process it.

Comment: Gabe, so over a 3g connection, there could be some cases where the JSON is not fully received? I.E, when the connection is lost in the middle of a request

Answer (score 0):

An easy work around would be to bundle a received object on the end:

[{normal objects}  .....  , {"received"}:"yes"}  ]

list.get(list.size() - 1) and check if recieved

then loop as normal to max of list.size() - 1

Like I said, it's a work around...